# How to allow chrome extension to access his path and files

Tags: javascript, plugins, firefox-addon, opera-extension

I'm making an opera extension and I want to get some images stored inside the extension path.

What the plugin does is, on a specific web page, change the image url from the background and some icons to custom ones inside the extension.

However when I run the script everything become invisible, meaning it failed to load the images.

Inside the logger I see `chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED` but when I log the path it seem normal.

Inside the `manifest.json` file I have the `webRequest` and `storage` permissions, also the plugin has permission to read user files I have double checked.

**Am I missing a permission that lock me out? Does manifest 3 not allow to change a background image?**

I also tried to run the same script on Firefox but everything works are it should.

```js
// get image folder from current plugin path.
let extFolder = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/"); // chrome
//let extFolder = extension.getURL("images/");    // firefox

// should look like: chrome-extension://<id>/images/
console.log(extFolder);

// get element to change.
let board = document.getElementById("board");

// change image.
board.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + extFolder + "board.png')";
```

The script I've wrote look like this, now why it does not work on opera?

I also tried to embeed these images as base64 but, since each image is very big, not all elements render the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what's the problem... is manifest 3.

The reason it works on firefox is because I've used manifest version 2, meanwhile opera uses version 3 instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).